# .getElementByClassName is unreliable. How else can I point to an HTML element with no ID?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a JavaScript novice.

I'm currently trying to write a chrome extension for a website we use at work (to create customer quotes) that will take the "parts" value and the "tax" value as inputs and add them together and output a "deposit" value.

The only problem is that there are no ID's on the DIV elements that hold the values I need.

I can reference the "parts" value okay using

```
document.getElementsByClassName ("col-xs-7 text-right")[2].innerText
```

since the "parts" element seems to consistently be the 3rd element with that class, but the "tax" element isn't consistently in the same place. Sometimes it will be the 3rd element with that class, sometime's it'll be the 5th, etc... I know there has to be a better way. The "tax" element looks like:

```
<div _ngcontent-c11="" class="col-xs-6 text-right">
    <button _ngcontent-c11="" class="_button _blank _tiny"><i _ngcontent-c11="" class="fas fa-pencil"></i></button>
    <!---->
    <!---->
    $0.00
    <!---->
    </div>
```

(I don't think the edit button is relevant, but I figured I'd keep it just in case.)

and the "parts" element looks like:

```
<div _ngcontent-c11="" class="col-xs-7 text-right">$0.00</div>
```

Comment: please show enough real HTML to get a useful answer - why can't you add an ID, or even another class to the tax element - makes life easier

Comment: `Sometimes it will be the 3rd element with that class, sometime's it'll be the 5th` Can you post a fuller example of the HTML, such as other elements with the class? There's almost certainly a distinguishing factor

Comment: perhaps you can start from a known parent of the desired elements and traverse the DOM downwards to reach them. Then there might be only one element with that class within the parent? Just a guess or idea really,  we can't see enough of the HTML structure to know, but I imagine you could identify such a thing, if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help! I was able to traverse the DOM tree, starting with a parent element that was unique enough to reference, and just drilled down until I got to the element I needed.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('col-xs-12 col-md-6 grid-item')[1].childNodes[17].childNodes[5].innerText
```

Comment: So `.getElementsByClassName` seems to have actually turned out to be *reliable* for you after all.  You might want to change the question title.